# wget and curl creating strange files in cron.d

Tags: ubuntu, cron, curl, wget

I've been messing around with cron recently, I wanted to create a simple cronjob that will send a simple GET request to a website, every minute. Everything would have worked if not for some strange files appearing in cron.d (which seem like some SSL certificates but are in some binary format (I could read header though) but some are normal text files ). I've tried sending files and output to `/dev/null` but to no avail files keep appearing. I get them every time I use `curl` or `wget`.

The files in question have the following names:

```
010.000.000.050.33322-083.030.008.062.00080
010.000.000.050.33334-083.030.008.062.00080
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33324
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33336
010.000.000.050.33322-083.030.008.062.00080c1
010.000.000.050.33334-083.030.008.062.00080c1
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33324c1
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33336c1
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33324c2
083.030.008.062.00080-010.000.000.050.33336c2
...
```

There are many more of those and they are being created every time I call `wget` or `curl`, despite setting them to redirect everything to `/dev/null` both with simple redirect on std::out and std::err and also with wget redirect flag (`-O`) to null (I've also set `-q`). I turned off my cronjob in `crontab`, but they are still appearing after calling both programs.

My question: What are those files, and can I somehow stop them from appearing?

Comment: Please, **1)** show us the exact cmds you issue from `cron`. **2)** Test for exit codes on those commands. **3)** Specify above-mentioned file locations... **4)** Last report to us (if you wish) by adding an **EDIT** section at the end of your original post. **5)** Expect more questions.

Comment: Ha ! and you can also show us your `~/.wgetrc` file if you tweaked it in any way... ;-)  Meanwhile I have the answer to question 3: `/etc/cron.d/`.   ;-)

Comment: You could run `file` on a few of them, in case they have a magic number. You could ls -l a few of them -- the size might indicate if they are complete copies of your downloads. You could check your Linux mailbox -- cron sends mail in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it.

A program called `tcpflow` (that is used for monitoring HTTP traffic in my case) was creating those files. I must have run `tcpflow` while I was in `/etc/cron.d` and it started doing it's thing. That would also explain "strange" file names that are just a set of IP addresses.

```
//from tcpflow man page
By default tcpflow stores all captured data in files that have names of the form:
192.168.101.102.02345-010.011.012.013.45103
...here the contents of the above file would be data transmitted from host 192.168.101.102 port 2345, to host 10.11.12.13 port 45103.
```

That would explain why calling `wget`/`curl` on HTTP and HTTPS had been creating those files. I should have read the manual :)

I've ended up killing `tcpflow` processes (I've got 3 of them running at once, that explains 3 copies of the same file marked with c1 and c2 respectively)